# What is legacy mode in hybris synchronization?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to synchronize products, but speed is around 2 items/sec. On setting synchronization.legacy.mode=true, the speed increases to around 25 items/sec. Based on documentation this property skips the service layer and no interceptors or restrictions are called.
Is it safe to set this property? What could be the reason for such poor performance (validated the sequence of root types, no slow db queries etc found) ? version: 1905.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your business rules. You already shared that interceptors, restrictions may be validations not running.

Some of products have missing mandatory attributes, such as description, price, image, stock, etc can be synchronized to prod system. Also this mode ignores errors and complete process.

You can get more detail from [this blog post](https://ecommercecandles.com/sap_hybris_commerce/cms_cockpit_wcms/common_reasons_of_synchronisation_failures).